# How do I get a neat table that is 2600px & 25 columns wide with Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a table that has 25 columns, and in total is about 2600px wide.

Right now, I have the structure as stated below - but it is flowing outside of the `content` area, and the content in each column is not aligned properly. In fact, content that should be on one line, is appearing on 2 or 3 in each row. It generally looks untidy.

I suspect that is because Twitter Bootstrap was made for smaller data sets - especially tables.

But does anyone have any ideas about how I might get this table to not look unwieldy?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="content">
           <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">

              <h2>Home</h2>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Phone</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Co. Name</th>
      <th>Co. Phone</th>
      <th>Co. Size</th>    
      <th>Co. Type</th>    
      <th>City</th>
      .
      .
      .    
    </tr>
  </thead>  

  <tr>
    <td>John F Kennedy</td>
    <td>87698765</td>
    <td>jfk@email.com</td>
     <!-- Begin Firm Info Here -->
        <td>Acme Inc</td>
        <td>(876) 987-6543</td>
       .
       .
       .
    </tr>
   </table>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want horizontal scroll?

Comment: Sure...anything that will make it more manageable to read. I am using Bootstrap 2.0 by the way. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To avoid line breaks you can use

```
.the-table {
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: none;
    width: auto;
}
```

This will force an horizontal scroll on the container of the `<table>` (or in the browser if that container can expand). So, if you want to control its layout, you can put the `<table>` inside a `<div>` with `overflow: auto` and a set `width`. You can use a Bootstrap "span" with an extra class:

```
.the-container {
    overflow: auto;
    /* width cames from spanN class */
}
```

Comment: I would also recommend adding `min-width: 100%` to `.the-table`